# Manual focus in camera2, android

Tags: android, camera, camera2

i am looking for an example of manual focus in camera2 in android. 
I tried to get minimum focus distance and available focal lengths shown below, but it didn't help. How to control the focus distance ?

```
float minimumLens = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);

float[] lensDistances = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);&nbsp;
```

I need to control it with seekbar.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 switch (seekBar.getId()) {
            case R.id.sb_focus:
                float minimumLens = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
                float num = (((float) i) * minimumLens / 100);
                mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, num);
                int showNum = (int) num;
                mSeekBarTextView.setText("focus：" + showNum);
                break;}
```

be careful ,CONTROL_AF_MODE should be OFF.
https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/androidltest/ui/DisplayFragment.java

code in Line 1109

Comment: what about manual focus for a single area ? How can i do that?

Comment: @yydcdut: Unfortunately this solution does not work on the Samsung Galaxy S7. While I haven't tried it on any other samsung phone, I strongly suspect that most samsung phones suffer from the problem.

Comment: Just for future readers, I believe in this sample code you want: mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, minimumLens);
It's not clear what exactly num is, but it's somehow related to the percentage of the focal distance, probably for the seekBar.

Comment: What's "i" variable ?

Comment: @SebastienFerrand "i" is seekbar progress