# How do I manually set the camera focus distance on android?

Tags: android

Say I want to take pictures a set focus distances. How can I go about this? I cant find anything about this in the Android documentation.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28170491/6950238) questions and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Camera Parameters referenced from here: [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

You can also see some example here: [How to set camera focus value manually in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207810/how-to-set-camera-focus-value-manually-in-android)